# cloudformation - apigateway stages to multiple lambda alias and version

Tags: aws-cloudformation

How can I deploy APIGateway stages for already lambda alias and version to specific stage, means I dont want to update lambda again, but I want to do mapping to the new stage or update the existing stage with specific lambda alias

i.e I have myFunction version 2,3 and alias dev, test and stage.
want to map stage of /dev to $LATEST, /test to alias test with version 2, /stage to alias with version 3.

How to achieve this.

I have tried with `${!stageVariables.lambdaAlias}` on Method Integration but I get internal server with log says Invalid permission

````
  apiGateway:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    Properties:
      Name: "StacksampleapidevNewPOC"
      Description: "SAMPLE New Template API"

  apiGatewayResource:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt
            - apiGateway
            - RootResourceId     
      PathPart: "MyFunction"
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"

  ApiAuthorizer: 
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer"
      Properties: 
        AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300
        IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
        Name: CognitoDefaultUserPoolAuthorizer
        ProviderARNs: 
          - arn:aws:cognito-idp:ap-south-1:accountid:userpool/poolid
        RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
        Type: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"

  apiGatewayStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      StageName: sampledev
      TracingEnabled: Yes
      DeploymentId: !Ref "apiGatewayDeployment"
      Variables: 
        ClientMaster: ClientMaster_dev
        UserMaster: UserMaster_dev
        RedisCacheEndpoint: !Ref RedisCacheEndpoint
        UserClientMapping: UserClientMapping_dev
        lambdaAlias: dev

  apiGatewayStage1:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      StageName: sampletest
      TracingEnabled: Yes
      DeploymentId: !Ref "apiGatewayDeployment"
      Variables: 
        ClientMaster: ClientMaster_dev
        UserMaster: UserMaster_dev
        RedisCacheEndpoint: !Ref RedisCacheEndpoint
        UserClientMapping: UserClientMapping_dev
        lambdaAlias: test

  apiGatewayStage2:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      StageName: samplestage
      TracingEnabled: Yes
      DeploymentId: !Ref "apiGatewayDeployment"
      Variables: 
        ClientMaster: ClientMaster_dev
        UserMaster: UserMaster_dev
        RedisCacheEndpoint: !Ref RedisCacheEndpoint
        UserClientMapping: UserClientMapping_dev
        lambdaAlias: stage

  apiGatewayRootMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
      AuthorizerId: !Ref ApiAuthorizer
      HttpMethod: POST
      Integration:
        Type: "AWS_PROXY"
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub        
          - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}:${!stageVariables.lambdaAlias}/invocations"       
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt "MyFunction.Arn"
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: ''
            ResponseParameters:
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: $input.json('$')
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.querystring.name: false
      ResourceId: !Ref "apiGatewayResource"
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: Empty
          ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
          StatusCode: '200'

  apiGatewayCORSOptionMethod:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
      Properties:
        ResourceId: !Ref apiGatewayResource
        RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        HttpMethod: OPTIONS
        Integration:
          Type: MOCK
          IntegrationResponses:
            - ResponseParameters:
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
              ResponseTemplates:
                application/json: ''
              StatusCode: '200'
          PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
          RequestTemplates:
            application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'
        MethodResponses:
          - ResponseModels:
              application/json: Empty
            ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
            StatusCode: '200'

  apiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment"
    DependsOn: apiGatewayRootMethod
    # DependsOn: [
      # apiGatewayRootMethod,
      # GetRightMenuapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # GetAreaapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # ResetRedisCacheapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # # GetChartsByUseCaseIDapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # ShowUserClientMappingsapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # GetChartKPIValuesapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # GetChartUseCaseMappingsapiGatewayRootMethod]
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      # StageName: !Ref "apiGatewayStageName"


  MyFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: PwC.SAMPLE.Lambda::PwC.SAMPLE.Lambda.Functions.Common.MyFunction::Run
      FunctionName: MyFunction_LambdaName
      Runtime: dotnetcore2.1
      Code:
        S3Bucket: "s3-sample-api-dev"
        S3Key: !Ref "CodeZip"
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 30
      Role:
        Ref: Role
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          Ref: SecurityGroupIds
        SubnetIds:
          Ref: SubnetIds

  MyFunctionVersion:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Ref: MyFunction

  MyFunctionAliasDev: 
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: 
        Ref: MyFunction
      FunctionVersion: devversion
      Name: dev

  # MyFunctionAliasDev: 
    # Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    # Properties: 
      # FunctionName: 
        # Ref: MyFunction
      # FunctionVersion: 
        # Fn::GetAtt:
        # - MyFunctionVersion
        # - Version
      # Name: dev

  MyFunctionAliasTest: 
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: 
        Ref: MyFunction
      FunctionVersion: testversion
      Name: test       

  MyFunctionAliasStage: 
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: 
        Ref: MyFunction
      FunctionVersion: stageversion
      Name: stage

  MyFunctionlambdaApiGatewayInvoke:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !GetAtt "MyFunction.Arn"
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/*/POST/MyFunction"```
````

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this with following changes on cloudformation template by calling Lambda permission by each alias created.

Now I can see each lambda alias and version has permission to APIGateway call Lambda function

Here is the sample yaml code I used to fix this issue.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "My API Gateway and Lambda function"

Parameters:
  apiGatewayStageName:
    Type: "String"
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-z0-9]+$"
    Default: "samplesample"
  Role:
    Type: String
    Default: arn:aws:iam::accountid:role/Fincockpit_AuroraServerless
    Description: ''
  SecurityGroupIds: 
    Default: "sgid"
    Description: ""
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  SubnetIds: 
    Default: "subnet"
    Description: ""
    Type: CommaDelimitedList    
  Policies:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: AWSLambdaFullAccess,AmazonRDSFullAccess,AmazonEC2FullAccess,AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess,AmazonVPCFullAccess
    Description: ''
  CodeZip:
    Type: String
    Description: SAMPLE API Build Package
  RedisCacheEndpoint:
    Type: String
    Default: 'redisendpoint'
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: sample
  S3Bucket:
    Type: String
    Default: s3-changeme-api-sample                               
  # AliasName:
    # Type: String
    # Default: stagename
  FunctionVersion:
    Type: String
    Default: commitid

Resources:
  apiGateway:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    Properties:
      Name: "StackchangemeapisampleNewPOC"
      Description: "SAMPLE New Template API"

  apiGatewayResource:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt
            - apiGateway
            - RootResourceId     
      PathPart: "MyFunction"
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"

  ApiAuthorizer: 
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer"
      Properties: 
        AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300
        IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
        Name: CognitoDefaultUserPoolAuthorizer
        ProviderARNs: 
          - arn:aws:cognito-idp:ap-south-1:accountid:userpool/poolid
        RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
        Type: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"

  apiGatewayStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      StageName: changemesample
      TracingEnabled: Yes
      DeploymentId: !Ref "apiGatewayDeployment"
      Variables: 
        ClientMaster: ClientMaster_sample
        UserMaster: UserMaster_sample
        RedisCacheEndpoint: !Ref RedisCacheEndpoint
        UserClientMapping: UserClientMapping_sample
        lambdaAlias: sample

  apiGatewayStage1:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      StageName: changemetest
      TracingEnabled: Yes
      DeploymentId: !Ref "apiGatewayDeployment"
      Variables: 
        ClientMaster: ClientMaster_test
        UserMaster: UserMaster_ctest
        RedisCacheEndpoint: "sample-redis-test.hreh1d.ng.0001.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379"
        UserClientMapping: UserClientMapping_test
        lambdaAlias: test

  apiGatewayStage2:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      StageName: samplestage
      TracingEnabled: Yes
      DeploymentId: !Ref "apiGatewayDeployment"
      Variables: 
        ClientMaster: ClientMaster_stage
        UserMaster: UserMaster_stage
        RedisCacheEndpoint: "sample-redis-stage.hreh1d.ng.0001.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379"
        UserClientMapping: UserClientMapping_stage
        lambdaAlias: stage

  apiGatewayRootMethod:
    DependsOn: [
      MyFunctionlambdaApiGatewayInvokeDev,
      MyFunctionlambdaApiGatewayInvokeTest,
      MyFunctionlambdaApiGatewayInvokeStage]
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
      AuthorizerId: !Ref ApiAuthorizer
      HttpMethod: POST
      Integration:
        Type: "AWS_PROXY"
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub        
          - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}:${!stageVariables.lambdaAlias}/invocations"       
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt "MyFunction.Arn"
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: ''
            ResponseParameters:
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: $input.json('$')
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.querystring.name: false
      ResourceId: !Ref "apiGatewayResource"
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: Empty
          ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
          StatusCode: '200'

  apiGatewayCORSOptionMethod:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
      Properties:
        ResourceId: !Ref apiGatewayResource
        RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        HttpMethod: OPTIONS
        Integration:
          Type: MOCK
          IntegrationResponses:
            - ResponseParameters:
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
              ResponseTemplates:
                application/json: ''
              StatusCode: '200'
          PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
          RequestTemplates:
            application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'
        MethodResponses:
          - ResponseModels:
              application/json: Empty
            ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
            StatusCode: '200'

  apiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment"
    DependsOn: apiGatewayRootMethod
    # DependsOn: [
      # apiGatewayRootMethod,
      # GetRightMenuapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # GetAreaapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # ResetRedisCacheapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # # GetChartsByUseCaseIDapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # ShowUserClientMappingsapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # GetChartKPIValuesapiGatewayRootMethod,
      # GetChartUseCaseMappingsapiGatewayRootMethod]
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
      # StageName: !Ref "apiGatewayStageName"


  MyFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: PwC.SAMPLE.Lambda::PwC.SAMPLE.Lambda.Functions.Common.MyFunction::Run
      FunctionName: MyFunction_LambdaName
      Runtime: dotnetcore2.1
      Code:
        S3Bucket: "s3-sample-api-sample"
        S3Key: !Ref "CodeZip"
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 30
      Role:
        Ref: Role
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          Ref: SecurityGroupIds
        SubnetIds:
          Ref: SubnetIds

  MyFunctionVersion:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Ref: MyFunction

  MyFunctionAliasDev: 
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: 
        Ref: MyFunction
      FunctionVersion: 
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - MyFunctionVersion
        - Version
      Name: dev

  MyFunctionAliasTest: 
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: 
        Ref: MyFunction
      FunctionVersion: testversion
      Name: test       

  MyFunctionAliasStage: 
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
    Properties: 
      FunctionName: 
        Ref: MyFunction
      FunctionVersion: stageversion
      Name: stage

  MyFunctionlambdaApiGatewayInvokeDev:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !Ref "MyFunctionAliasDev"
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/*/POST/MyFunction"

  MyFunctionlambdaApiGatewayInvokeTest:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !Ref "MyFunctionAliasTest"
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/*/POST/MyFunction"      

  MyFunctionlambdaApiGatewayInvokeStage:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !Ref "MyFunctionAliasStage"
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/*/POST/MyFunction"
```